# What does static mean when applied to a class at namespace scope?

Tags: c++, class, object, static, linkage

I know that `static` at namespace scope means "internal linkage". Now consider the following code:

```
static class Foo {} foo;
```

Does the `static` apply to `Foo`, `foo` or both?

Comment: That's fairly simple to test... remove the `foo` and read the error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It applies to the variable declared after the class definition.

In C++, there is no such thing as `static class`. There are only `static` objects and `static` functions.

Comment: static appears in a lot more places than that.

Comment: A static POD within a function for example.

Comment: @Lou: What is that? Explain. How can you define static POD within a function?

Comment: int next(){ static int mystatic = 0; return my static++; }

Comment: @Lou: What does it show? Doesn't it contain `static` object? Didn't I say that already?

Answer (score 7):

`class Foo {}` states type of `foo` variable. `static` makes `foo` static.